# Typescript generic angular forms with optional properties

Tags: angular, typescript

Give the following, how can I make my optional properties be optional inside the FormBuilder?

```
export type TypedFormControls<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Array<infer R>
    ? FormArray<
        R extends Record<any, any>
          ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<R>>
          : FormControl<R>
      >
    : T[K] extends Record<any, any>
    ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<T[K]>>
    : FormControl<T[K]>;
};
```

Here are my models

```
export class UserModel {
  email: string;
  age?: number;
  information?: Information;
}

export class Information {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  gender?: string;
}
```

And finally the form group

```
this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group<TypedFormControls<UserModel>>({
      email: this._formBuilder.control('email@email'),
      // age: this._formBuilder.control(25),
      information: this._formBuilder.group<TypedFormControls<Information>>({
        // gender: this._formBuilder.control('male'),
        id: this._formBuilder.control(1),
        name: this._formBuilder.control('John'),
      }),
    });
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qz9hdz)

Comment: stackblitz link broken

Comment: I would avoid using a formBuilder at all, and just build the form up manually, and not assign validators.required to those optional controls.

Comment: @AndrewAllen it should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fqjstc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export type TypedFormControls<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Array<infer R>
    ? FormArray<
        R extends Record<any, any>
          ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<R>>
          : FormControl<R>
      >
    : T[K] extends Record<any, any>
    ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<T[K]>>
    : FormControl<T[K]>;
};

export class UserModel {
  email: string;
  age: number | null;
  information: Information | null;
}

export class Information {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  gender: string | null;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group<TypedFormControls<UserModel>>({
      email: this._formBuilder.control('email@email'),
      age: this._formBuilder.control(25),
      information: this._formBuilder.group<TypedFormControls<Information>>({
        gender: this._formBuilder.control('male'),
        id: this._formBuilder.control(1),
        name: this._formBuilder.control('John'),
      }),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I redefined your nullable types with | null.

Comment: But the idea is to have those nullable properties be optional inside the formbuilder - the TypeFormControls needs some reworking, I just don't know how to rework it to allow for optional properties.

Comment: A property defined as string | null is a nullable property.  It can take either a string or null.  If your problem is validation, then just don't use a FormBuilder, but build it up yourself.  Honestly I think it's easier than a form builder.  Then don't add Validators.required to the properties that aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the initial example is making all properties required, so instead of `[K in keyof T]-?` if I use `[K in keyof T]` the optional properties remain which is exactly the result I am looking for.